# Oracle Apex: error trying to run a translated application

Tags: oracle-apex, translation

I tried to translate an App (ID 518) from french to english following steps from [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/understanding-application-translation-and-globalization-support.html#GUID-C5CBC233-7557-49E2-8D4C-CCA952D47257), on **Oracle Apex 19.1**.

I edited the XLIFF file, replacing all `target` elements with my translation. I then published the translated app (ID 519) using this XLIFF file.

The problem is I cannot run the App as I get this error:

[image: Error while running the translated app]

As Oracle documentation specifies:

> You should verify the existence of the translated application after it
> is published. Translated applications do not display in the Available
> Applications list on the App Builder home page. Instead, use the
> Application Navigate list on the left side of the page.
>
> Note that in order for a translated application to appear in App
> Builder, you must ensure that you have correctly configured the
> application Globalization attributes.

Indeed I do not see the translated app in the app builder, I access it by typing the new app ID in the search field which redirect me towards it. There I see all pages numbers are of this format: `x.519`as 519 is the new app ID. I don't know if it's normal or not, but anyway when I try to run it, I get the above error. Plus, when I click to edit a Page I get an infinite load, the page never opens. Also, I am not sure what they mean by *"you must ensure that you have correctly configured the application Globalization attributes"*, but I tried setting Globalization attributes according to the new app language, it does not change anything.

Anyone with some experience translating apps ? I'd gladly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my understanding of how translation works. In fact, you just need to run the original application. There's no point in trying to run the translated one.

Globalization attributes define if the original app must be used, or one of the translated ones.